# Create columns with an array in a loop in sas

Tags: loops, sas

I want to create five target year columns to the work.komposit_prod throug a loop.
I got following code:

```
proc sql noprint;
select distinct year into :targetyears1 - FROM work.QE_Target
ORDER by year;
quit;


proc sql noprint;
  select distinct Count(Jahr) into :Count_targetyears 
  FROM 
      (select distinct year FROM work.QE_Target);
quit;

%let max = &Count_targetyears;

data test ;
set work.komposit_prod;
Do i=1 to &max;
"ZZ_&&targetyears&i"n = .;

end;
run;
```

Somehow the variable "ZZ_&&targetyears&i"n reference couldn't be resolved.
Can someone give me a hint?
Thank you.

Kind regars,
Ben

Comment: In your second proc sql statement you have Jahr instead of year as name of a variable.

Comment: my fault, of course it has to be year. But it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your do loop references a data step variable rather than a macro variable:

```
Do i=1 to &max;
    "ZZ_&&targetyears&i"n = .;
end;
```

You will need to convert this to a macro to run it:

```
%macro target_years;
    data test ;
        set work.komposit_prod;
        %do i=1 to &max;
            "ZZ_&&targetyears&i"n = .;
        %end;
    run;
%mend;
%target_years
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stu Sztukowski, this works fine.